# XMLHTTPRequest responseBody vs responseText

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

I've always referenced the body property on an XMLHTTPRequest response because it's always a nice usable parsed js object. But this time body is null and the response is sitting there stringified in .text and I'd like to know why that might be, and the tradeoffs to using one over the other in server / client interactions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your server is responding with the wrong `Content-Type` header. Ensure it is set to something reasonable like `application/json`.